# Can't add activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add another activity to my project but it seems like the options for that are greyed out

Here's what it looks like to me:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your minimum SDK level. That's why it's greyed out - yours is set to be too low.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, right under `<manifest . . . >`, add this:

```
 uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```

You can change the value there to any value...you only really need 8 or higher for most of the activities you are trying to add.

Comment: Another reason is if you run your application in release mode you cant create activity .so change to debug mode when creating new activity.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem to solve.

Go to Gradle and check the following settings:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hawiLLC.hawiblogapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Check on the minimum `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: If you change the minSDKVersion to 15 or higher, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In order to change the minumun SDK level in a Android Studio project I had to change it in `build.gradle`instead of the `AndroidManifest.xml`. This is part of the file I modified:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myfirstapp"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Natalia Marta- excellent point. I was still left unsuccessful until i read your point. And YES, only after i changed it in the build.gradle was i then able to add the activity.